# UWP: PointerPressed is not fired on a child element

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling, mouseevent, event-bubbling

I have an UWP App where a RelativePanel "parent" contains another RelativePanel "child".
Both of them should be able to handle the PointerPressed event, in different ways.

When I click on the parent, the PointerPressed event handler of the parent is correctly fired, but when I click on the child, again only the PointerPressed event handler of the parent is fired, so that the PointerPressed event handler of the child is never invoked.

How can I configure the child so that its PointerPressed event handler is invoked?

Here's an excerpt of the code to create these elements (everything is done in the code behind, since those elements should be created at runtime):

```
public class ChildView
{
    public RelativePanel View { get; set; }

    public ChildView()
    {
        View.Width = 18;
        View.Height = 18;
        View.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 30);  // we want the child always on top of the parent
        View.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        // Add the gesture recognizers:
        View.Holding += HandleLongPressGesture;
        View.PointerPressed += HandleTapGesture;
        View.PointerReleased += HandlePointerReleased;
        View.DoubleTapped += HandleDoubleTapGesture;
    }

    public void HandleLongPressGesture(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // my logic
    }
    private void HandlePointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // my logic
    }
    private void HandleDoubleTapGesture(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // my logic
    }
    private void HandleTapGesture(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // my logic
    }
}

public class ParentView
{
    private ChildView child;

    public RelativePanel View { get; set; }

    public ParentView()
    {
        child = new ChildView();
        View.Children.Add(child.View);
        View.PointerPressed += HandleTapGesture;
        View.PointerReleased += HandlePointerReleased;
    }

    private void HandlePointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // my logic
    }
    private void HandleDoubleTapGesture(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // my logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your XAML please?

Comment: It is all code behind because those elements must be created at runtime, but I added a summary for that code

Answer (score 0):

set the background of your child panel to transparent.

when the event fires, make sure you do the .Handled=true;
 on the incoming handler args to prevent propagation to the parent control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this isn't exactly an answer to your question, but maybe it will help you to debug in some way.

Okay so I set up a simple project (before you added your code to the question) and was unable to replicate your issue.

Basically, the Child click event was getting fired correctly, then the Parent click event was getting fired immediately after, which seems correct to me in this instance.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <RelativePanel Name="Parent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="460" Margin="437,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="458" Background="#FFFF5C5C" PointerPressed="Parent_PointerPressed">
        <RelativePanel Name="Child" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="360" Margin="62,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334" Background="#FF3B9C9C" PointerPressed="Child_PointerPressed"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
    private void Parent_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Breaks here when Parent is pressed
        // Also breaks here after breaking on Child_PointerPressed
    }

    private void Child_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Breaks here when Child is pressed
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, I have a similar test project and I have the same behavior. To be fully transparent, the PointerPressed event is not fired *in some occasions*, not always, but I don't yet understand the conditions when it fires and when it doesn't. So I was looking for the broader (un-biased) answer, to see if I was doing something wrong in my setup...

Comment: Any further ideas here? Thank you!

Comment: @CristianoGhersi as I'm unable to replicate the issue, I'm afraid not. If you could create a sample project and upload it to GitHub, I will surely take a look and let you know my findings...

Comment: OK I will try to pack a minimum project that reproduce the issue